# Got "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Trancel'" when using two paramenters in detailview in Django

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, detailview

I am trying to use two other url tags other then pk and slug in a detail view. I have the following code snippet:

```
views.py

    class UseCaseDetailView(DetailView):
        template_name = "useCaseExtract/useCaseDetail.html"
        model = UseCaseProfile
        context_object_name = 'usecaseprofile'
        '''I am trying to override the get_object method of DetailView to accept url tags project and usecasename instead of pk and slug'''
        def get_object(self):     
            obj = get_object_or_404(UseCaseProfile, project=self.kwargs['project'], useCasename=self.kwargs['useCasename'])
            return obj

urls.py
...

    path('/UseCaseDetail/', UseCaseDetailView.as_view(), name='UseCaseDetail')

...

in my template file, I have the following link:
/Trancel/UseCaseDetail/Nothing

after I clicked the link, I got:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:  'Trancel'

can you some please explain to me why I am getting this error?
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the ability to rename `Trance1` to something like `TranceOne`? So that it doesn't include an integer?

I think your issue is that `1` when it comes time to parse the URL..( as its expecting a sting, but it gets string w/ a `1` in it).

Comment: I figured out the issue. The project url tag is for a foreign key in the model that I will be querying. 
I modified the get_object code in the detailview as below.
def get_object(self):
        project=Project.objects.all()
        x=project.filter(projectName=self.kwargs['project'])
        print(self.kwargs['project'])
        print(self.kwargs['useCasename'])  
        obj = get_object_or_404(UseCaseProfile, project=x.first(), useCasename=self.kwargs['useCasename'])
        return obj

Answer (score 0):

The project url tag is a foreign key in the UseCaseProfile model. In order to query the UseCaseProfile, I modified the get_object code in the detailview as below.

```
def get_object(self):
        project=Project.objects.all()
        x=project.filter(projectName=self.kwargs['project'])
        obj = get_object_or_404(UseCaseProfile, project=x.first(), useCasename=self.kwargs['useCasename'])
        return obj
```